# Purity of revenge won't start. Skyrim: 360

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok, so I completed the helm of winterhold quest and it won't let me start purity of revenge. I waited 30 in game days and nothing. And since finding the problem, I have already defeated alduin and accomplished so much so reloading a save isn't an option. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This quest has [significant bugs that can prevent it from ever starting](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Purity_of_Revenge#Bugs). For your situation in particular, it sounds like you are stuck and won't ever be able to start it on this save:

> If Driftshade Refuge has already been cleared, this quest cannot be started normally without a workaround[…] (you will have to revert to a slightly earlier save to do this).

Since you probably cleared Driftshade Refuge during Helm of Winterhold, then only reverting to a previous save or using console commands (on PC only) can make Purity of Revenge start.